# C# Send E-Mail issue

Tags: c#, email, send

I'm trying to send an e-mail in C#,and I'm having some issues.Whenever I try to send an e-mail,I get a message "Error: Failure to send mail".
Here is my code:

```
    try
        {
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 465;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = smtpCreds;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailAddress sendFrom = new MailAddress("from@domain.com");
            MailAddress sendTo = new MailAddress("to@domain.com");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(sendFrom,sendTo);
            msg.Subject = "Subject";
            msg.Body = "Body";
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message);
        }
```

Also I have this declaration:

```
    public SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    public System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "password");
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried with `Port = 587`

Comment: @Sachin I have. Still doesn't work

Comment: Is there an `InnerExceptoin`?

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud The only Exception caught is when I try to send the mail. That is all

Comment: @Stormel, an `Exception` class has an `InnerException` property. Is that property `null`? You'd have to put a breakpoint here `MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this and make sure you are using valid login credential and you have internet connection:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
 mail.From = new MailAddress("senderMailAddress");
 mail.To.Add("ReceiverMailAddress");
 mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 NetworkCredential netCre = new NetworkCredential("SenderMailAddress","SenderPassword" );
 smtp.Credentials = netCre;

 try
  {
   smtp.Send(mail);                
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {               
  }
```

Comment: check your user name and password and also put a break point at `catch` block

Comment: the username and password are ok. I did put a breakpoint at catch block,and it's stops there. for some reason it just won't send the email

Comment: you can check the exception

Comment: your code works for me , but i have one issue , the from mail is always equal to my NetworkCredentialMail , can anyone tell me what is wrong , and how can i get the from address

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
        using System.Net.Mail;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("reciever@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = ("e mail subject");
       mail.Body = ("message body");
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender's username",            "sender's password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```

Comment: Did you check your internet connection?

Comment: I can't see any problem with my internet connection. I have tried also connecting through a different internet provider. Same problem